# parsing and reformatting elements in Python3

Tags: xml, python-3.x, lxml, python-3.4

I have some xml with the element:

```
<seg id="1" text="some text"/>
```

which I want to reformat in python3 as:

```
<in_seg id="sent1"> some text</in_seg>
```

how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an element via instantiating an `Element` class:

```
from lxml.etree import fromstring, Element, tostring

data = """
<seg id="1" text="some text"/>
"""
element = fromstring(data)

tag_name = 'in_' + element.tag
tag_id = 'sent' + element.attrib['id']
tag_text = element.attrib['text']

new_element = Element(tag_name, attrib={'id': tag_id})
new_element.text = tag_text
print(tostring(new_element))
```

Prints:

```
<in_seg id="sent1">some text</in_seg>
```